# 'y' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmd

I have a problem about command prompt. I have a C++/Qt GUI desktop application on windows 7. But I also need to run this application from command prompt 
for example:

`myApp.exe -l myfile -ic`.

I can launch and use my app functionality from command prompt successfully but if I need to take an input from user on command prompt, I can not take inputs. When I enter an input, output is

> ```
>   Accept values? y(yes)n(no)
>   y
>  'y' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
> ```

I am taking user input like this:

```
char userResponse = 'n';
std::cin >> userResponse;
if (userResponse == 'y' || userResponse == 'Y' )
{               
    ...             
}

emit myWorkDone();
return false;
```

The problem is that program waits on waiting user input line. When myWorkDone signal is emitted, application quits for normal conditions.

In main

```
 QApplication a(argc,argv);
...
> QObject::connect(&argProcessor, SIGNAL(finishedProcessor()) ,&a,    
> SLOT(quit()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
>     
>       return a.exec(); // Main application
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: In order to understand the problem one needs to look at your source code to see how do you read the user's input and how do you process it.

Comment: I added how I take the input from user

Comment: Well, and what you do with this `userResponse` variable later? Please show how do you process the user's input.

Comment: Since you use an event loop in your console application (assuming from `a.exec()`), double check if the program executes the code taking user input, stops waiting for the input on the line `std::cin >> userResponse;` and no other thread takes the console input.

Comment: Do you mean that I should listen the console input with another thread?

Comment: I discovered that QApplication listens the console of application not Windows console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is that when console is closed in project properties in Visual Studio,  Project -> Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem.

When the Windows Console is turned on so console of my application is closed then QApplication does not take input from Windows Console.

[image]

I changed this to Console.

[image]

After that, QApplication can take input from Windows Console. But I do not want to show the console of my application to user. So I hided it in code by using :

```
        HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
```

Therefore, application can take input from user correctly and my console is hidden.